# c# linq query aggregation data with other column value

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

this is my environment.

I have a datatable with this kind of structure

**IDstring | Attrib1 | Attrib2 | Attrib3 | Attrib4 | Value**

I need to export average, max, min value group by attrib elements, and I use following code:

```
        var queryTable = from rows in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                         group rows by new
                         {
                             Attrib1 = rows["Attrib1"],
                             Attrib2 = rows["Attrib2"],
                             Attrib3 = rows["Attrib3"],
                             Attrib4 = rows["Attrib4"]
                         } into grp
                         select new
                         {
                             Attrib1 = grp.Key.Attrib1,
                             Attrib2 = grp.Key.Attrib2,
                             Attrib3 = grp.Key.Attrib4,
                             Attrib4 = grp.Key.Attrib14,
                             Avg = grp.Average(s => Convert.ToDouble(s["Value"])),
                             Min = grp.Min(s => Convert.ToDouble(s["Value"])),
                             Max = grp.Max(s => Convert.ToDouble(s["Value"])),
                             Count = grp.Count()
                         };
```

**If I need also to export one IDstring (not necessary all occurrence) that match max and min value, how can I do it?**

I have tried with another linq query for every max and min element of upon querytable results to the original datatable but it is too slow for the number of elements I have. Can you help me please?

Comment: Try `IdString = grp.FirstOrDefault().IDstring ;`. Not sure without seeing how your data looks.

Comment: Thanks you coder of code, it seems to work!!!

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: I am sorry Andreas, next time I will avoid ...

Answer (score 0):

With the big help of coder of code, this could be the solution:
First I make on order by Value and then i take first and last element.

```
        var queryTable = from rows in resultTable.AsEnumerable()
                         orderby rows.Field<double>("Value")
                         group rows by new
                         {
                             Attrib1 = rows["Attrib1"],
                             Attrib2 = rows["Attrib2"],
                             Attrib3 = rows["Attrib3"],
                             Attrib4 = rows["Attrib4"]
                         } into grp
                         select new
                         {
                             Attrib1 = grp.Key.Attrib1,
                             Attrib2 = grp.Key.Attrib2,
                             Attrib3 = grp.Key.Attrib3,
                             Attrib4 = grp.Key.Attrib4,
                             Avg = grp.Average(s => Convert.ToDouble(s["Value"])),
                             Min = grp.Min(s => Convert.ToDouble(s["Value"])),
                             IDStringMin = grp.First().Field<string>("IDstring"),
                             Max = grp.Max(s => Convert.ToDouble(s["Value"])),
                             IDStringMax = grp.Last().Field<string>("IDstring"),
                             Count = grp.Count()
                         };
```